# Где в FieldInfo хранится значение самого поля? C#

Tags: c#

Недавно начал изучать рефлексию и то, что находится под капотом. Сегодня начал разбираться с "внутренностями" полей. В итоге понял, что поля - это классы, которые хранят своё имя, тип, инфу о том, что это поле, значения перечисления FieldAttributes, значения перечисления BindingFlags, FieldHandle и т. д. и т. п., но я не смог найти само значение этого поля. Где в поле, то есть в FieldInfo, находится значение самого поля?

Comment: FieldInfo это информация о типе, а не о конкретном инстансе. У него [есть метод](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo?view=netcore-3.1) для извлечения значения, но в этот метод надо отправить инстанс класса с этим полем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Само поле хранится в куче, внутри структуры объекта:

<sub>Class.cs</sub>

```cs
public sealed class Class
{
    public int Field { get; set; }
}
```

<sub>Memory dump (x86) (выравнивание 4 байта)</sub>

```
╓───────────────────╥───────────────────╥───────────────────╖
║ Type Handle       ║ Sync Block Index  ║ Field (Наше поле) ║
╟────┬────┬────┬────╫────┬────┬────┬────╫────┬────┬────┬────╢
║ .. │ .. │ .. │ .. ║ .. │ .. │ .. │ .. ║ 00 │ 00 │ 00 │ 00 ║
╙────┴────┴────┴────╨────┴────┴────┴────╨────┴────┴────┴────╜
```

И вот эта вся канитель хранится в куче с остальными объектами.

`FieldInfo` на то и *`Info`*, что содержит только *информацию* о расположении поля, т. е. смещение (смещение отсчитывается от конца `Sync Block Index`), в нашем случае это `0`.

И когда мы пишем вот такой код:

```cs
var @class = new Class { Field = 0x11_22_33_44 };
var field = @class.GetType().GetField("Field")!;
var fieldValue = field.GetValue(@class);
```

…его (последнюю строчку) можно интерпретировать (грубо) вот так:

```c
typedef struct FieldInfo {
    ⋮ // прочая инфа
    size_t offset;
} FieldInfo;
⋮
long fieldValue = *(long*)((char*)class + 8 + field->offset); // работает только на x86
```